# Access uint8_t vector in Java via SWIG

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm working on a Java <-> C++ bridge using SWIG; my c++ method is as follows:

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> ArduGrabClass::grab() {
    IMAGE_FORMAT fmt = { IMAGE_ENCODING_I420, 100 };
    BUFFER *buffer = arducam_capture(camera_instance, &fmt, 352000);
    return vector<uint8_t>(buffer->data, buffer->data + buffer->length);
}
```

That is cut down, the real method holds onto the buffer object in the c++ class so that the java side can release it.  However I need to access this data on the Java side, preferably in a ByteBuffer otherwise in an array.  However I don't know how to do it; the JNI method [NewDirectByteBufer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewDirectByteBuffer) seems suitable but SWIG is handling all the JNI stuff so I don't know how to tell SWIG to use the NewDirectByteBufer method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally feasible to write a typemap to call `NewDirectByteBuffer`, but as written that's definitely not the right way to wrap your code. The problem as written is two fold:

1. You've returned a vector by value, but that means its memory is going to expire as soon as it goes out of scope, leaving the `ByteBuffer` referring to memory that's no longer valid
2. If you did extend the lifespan of the vector to avoid that issue there's currently nothing that would free that memory when the `ByteBuffer` get garbage collected so you'd leak memory
3. The call to `arducam_capture` itself needs to be paired with a call to `arducam_release_buffer` somehow - you could add that into your `ArduGrabClass::grab()` function, but see below
4. Even if you did all this you'd still be doing quite a few copies of the data, which somewhat defeats the point of using a ByteBuffer in Java. (There's at least going to be one copy in the constructor for the vector, maybe more depending on how you did solve it.

So if you want to use the `std::vector` copy, I'd recommend just using the existing SWIG support for `std::vector`, or maybe copying it into a new array in some JNI code. I can demonstrate how to do that if you are interested, but for now I've focused on the question of how to use `ByteBuffer` correctly with `arducam_capture`.

To have a Java method that returns a `ByteBuffer` and gets cleaned up afterwards we want to arrange to use a [Cleaner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) that spots when the `ByteBuffer` goes out of scope.

If we change our wrapped function to return the `BUFFER *` and not a copy of it in a `std::vector` we can use some SWIG support in the internals of the generated conversion to call an extra function we add into our wrapper that calls `NewDirectByteBuffer` for us. And then, inside that code we can also register the `ByteBuffer` with a `Runnable` that will call `arducam_release_buffer` for us.

An example of a SWIG interface that does this for us is:

```c
%module test

%pragma(java) modulecode=%{
   // Create a single cleaner thread for all our buffers to register with
   // note package level access is deliberate
   static final java.lang.ref.Cleaner cc = java.lang.ref.Cleaner.create();
   static {
     // actually load our shared object!
     System.loadLibrary("test");
   }
%}

// later on when we implement toBuffer() we need the environment pointer.
// This adds it into our method call automatically
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) JNIEnv * %{
  $1 = jenv;
%}

// Our native implementation of toBuffer on BUFFER is going to return
// a ByteBuffer straight up for us, with no need for conversions
%typemap(jtype) jobject toBuffer "java.nio.ByteBuffer"
%typemap(jstype) jobject toBuffer "java.nio.ByteBuffer"

// When we hand the ByteBuffer off to a caller we need to register
// something to do the clean up for us. This is where we register it.
%typemap(javaout) jobject toBuffer {
  java.nio.ByteBuffer buf = $jnicall; // actually call the native code
  System.out.println("In toBuffer"); // To prove it worked!

  // Our cleaner instance lives in the module itself
  $module.cc.register(buf, new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("in buffer cleanup java side");
      // We add a (private) cleanup function we can just call here
      BUFFER.this.cleanup();
    }
  });

  // Now it's registered actually let them have it
  return buf;
}

// Every time we return a BUFFER * call toBuffer() on it instead
%typemap(javaout) BUFFER * {
  return new $javaclassname($jnicall, $owner).toBuffer();
}

// Since we're going to call toBuffer() the return type is different
%typemap(jstype) BUFFER * "java.nio.ByteBuffer"

// Hide lots of thing about the BUFFER class outside our package
%typemap(javaclassmodifiers) BUFFER "class"
%javamethodmodifiers BUFFER::cleanup() "private";
%javamethodmodifiers BUFFER::toBuffer "";



// BEGIN Faked definitions, just for testing...
%{
typedef struct {
  void *data;
  int len;
} BUFFER;

typedef struct {
  enum { IMAGE_ENCODING_I420 } a;
  int n;
} IMAGE_FORMAT;

BUFFER * arducam_capture(void * instance, IMAGE_FORMAT *fmt, int timeout) {
  (void)instance; (void)fmt; (void)timeout;
  BUFFER *buf = malloc(sizeof *buf);
  *buf = (BUFFER){
    .data = malloc(100),
    .len = 100,
  };
  return buf;
}

void arducam_release_buffer(BUFFER *instance) {
  free(instance->data);
  free(instance);
}
%}
// END TESTING

// All the details of BUFFER are not public for Java users
%nodefaultctor BUFFER;
%nodefaultdtor BUFFER;
typedef struct {} BUFFER;

// In addition to what's really in the buffer object we want to add another
// two methods. 
%extend BUFFER {
        // toBuffer() is used by our internals when returning a BUFFER
        jobject toBuffer(JNIEnv *jenv) const {
                // Swig provides JCALLx macros for us, but they are not usable inside %extend :(
%#ifdef __cplusplus__
                return jenv->NewDirectByteBuffer($self->data, $self->len);
%#else
                return (*jenv)->NewDirectByteBuffer(jenv, $self->data, $self->len);
%#endif
        }

        // Cleanup is used when the buffer is dead
        void cleanup() {
                arducam_release_buffer($self);
        }
}


%inline %{
// Now, wrap a modified version of your code
BUFFER *do_capture() {
    void *camera_instance = NULL;
    IMAGE_FORMAT fmt = { IMAGE_ENCODING_I420, 100 };
    BUFFER *buffer = arducam_capture(camera_instance, &fmt, 352000);
    return buffer;
}

%}
```

And then to try it out:

```java
public class run {
        public static void main(String[] argv) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                        java.nio.ByteBuffer buf = test.do_capture();
                        System.gc();
                }
        }
}
```

Which we can then build and run:

```
swig3.0 -java -Wall test.i
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o libtest.so -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux test_wrap.c -shared 
javac *.java  -Xlint:deprecation 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. java run
In toBuffer
in buffer cleanup java side
......
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, in the question I wrote that the full code keeps a reference to the byte buffer and we will have an explicit java side call to release the buffer.  So all I need is the conversion wothout the cleaning stuff or am I missing something?  The reason I put the data in a vector is that the data is originally in an array with a pointer to the start, ideally I'd hand that pointer off and the Java side reads directly from there without a vector but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You definitely could do it like that but I'm not a fan of APIs in java that require the java developer to think about memory management differently to any other Java code. My preference is that even with buffers we arrange for everything to be automatic and correct at all times.

Comment: If you want to do it that way the out typemap can call the jni method for you though without needing %extend.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out as well that the direct byte buffer is doing reads straight out of the pointer you give it, which is mostly what my answer is doing just in slightly convoluted way.

Comment: Thanks so I can pass the pointer to the jni bytebuffer method.  I'm OK with an explicit call in Java, this will be used in one place and one place only. The data will be received, processed and sent off to a different processor for the next step all within a code block.